# Jenkins - run child build before aborting the main build

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins

I am looking for a way to make a build run another build right after stoping it (aka clicking a red cross button) but **BEFORE** actually aborting itself. Post-build Actions is not an option because it will run after the main job is killed/finished, therefore losing the data when child build is run. Passing parameters is also not an option; the reason for this is to keep the parent **PID** and pass it to second build. I could do it in script and set it as ENV variable but I don't want to do this for each Jenkins job.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with try catch, the catch block looking like this:

```
catch (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException e) {

    error = e
    currentBuild.result = "ABORTED"

    build 'your_other_job'
}
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to do this without touching the code?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it in the UI, if that's what you're asking.